# How to set the rotate center to be the center of the object iI want to rotate?

Tags: transforms

the cursor is at world origin, and I want to rotate, move, scale an object, but when I press the rotate/move/scale/ button, the rotate/move/scale center is at the world origin, the object I want to move is far away from world origin, how to set the rotate/move/scale center to be at the center of the object????

blender 2.81

Comment: This is just a question of setting the 'Transform Pivot Point' in the header of the 3D View?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to go to the *Object* menu, select *Transform* and then click on *Origin to Geometry*. This should solve your rotation and scaling problem.

It would also be good to *apply* scale and rotation to your object. (For the sake of future editing.) You can do this by going to **object > apply > scale & rotation.**

Comment: where is  Origin to Geometry.?

Comment: Origin to geometry is in the OBJECT tab

Comment: what is object tab?

Comment: On the top left. The menu tab next to the add tab.

Comment: the center of the transform is still at world origin, and there is a orange dot far away from the object, I can't move the object properly, it won't go to the location I move it to. why this software is so difficult to talk to

Comment: Move the cursor to where you want the transform to be, and select "Origin to 3D Cursor" which is right next to the origin to geometry option..

Comment: what is that orange dot? it moves together with the object, how can I set the orange dot to the center of the object?

Comment: The "orange dot" is the origin. Using the information I gave you about setting it's location, you can move it.

Comment: the orange dot is still away from the object

Comment: Maybe that is another object that you have accidentally selected.